# VisualStudio integration with GIT push

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

When I try to push my changes to GitHub using the Visual Studio integration I am prompted for a username and password which doesn't accept anything I type in. I am forced to go to a terminal window and issue 'git push' which does what I want and never prompts me for credentials. What am I doing wrong with VS? I notice that when I logout of GitHub and try to log back in the dialog indicates I could enter a user name OR email. I have tried my email and the user name that shows up in the repository URL (I am assuming that it is my user name).

Comment: Do you have 2FA activated on your GitHub account (https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/)

Comment: I think so? I know I have it on my dropbox account

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Tools-->Options-->SourceControl-->Plug-in** Selection
   *Make sure that you have Current Source Control Plug-In set to Git.*

   [image]
2. Click on Team Explorer Tab
    I use this tab rather than the Github tab.
    You should see Github under your connections, where you can sign in.  You can use either your email or username. Both should work.

   [image]
3. Now you should be able to clone or create a new local repository.  If you create a new local repository you should be able to Add and commit. Let me know if you have any issues and I'm happy to help further.

   [image]